# Performance of class compilation

Tags: performance, class, compilation, ocaml

Consider the following two code generators:

```
(echo "class foo = object" ; for ((i = 0; i < 2000; i++)) do echo method x$i = $i; done ; echo end) > test.ml
```

and

```
(echo "" ; for ((i = 0; i < 2000; i++)) do echo let x$i = $i; done ; echo) > test.ml
```

The former one creates one large class with a scalable amount of methods while the latter does the same with a (toplevel) module.

Albeit, the compiler behaves wastely different:

```
% time ocamlc test.ml
ocamlc test.ml  19,89s user 0,01s system 99% cpu 19,950 total

% time ocamlc test.ml 
ocamlc test.ml  0,29s user 0,01s system 99% cpu 0,305 total
```

If you play around with the loops limit, you will notice that the module can be compiled in linear time, while the class' compilation is quadratic. I wonder what causes this issue and if there is a way to avoid it?

Is it really inherent to OCaml's implementation of classes to have a quadratic compilation process? If so, is there a semantic equivalent way to split work and speed things up (i.e. inheritance)? I have to generate large classes since I rely on the late binding of class methods.

Comment: I bet this sort of questions of the compiler internals are better answered in caml-list mailing list.

Comment: Classes always do dynamic dispatch. For this they have a hashtable using the hash of the method name as key and the code as value. I bet that each new method you declare checks all the names of previous methods for a hash conflict.

Comment: Probably. But that would be an (amortized) O(1) operation, so it cannot/shouldnot be the problem.

Comment: Not sure this is inherent, but classes are not a priority to the OCaml dev team. It either comes from the typing checks it has to make or from the construction of the dynamic dispatch structure. This structure is a bit more complex than modules (modules are basically records).

Comment: You should probably post this as a bug report on the [OCaml bug tracker](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis).